# Terraform Terratest - undefined Destroy function error

Tags: go, terraform, infrastructure-as-code, terratest

Tried to run terratest over terraform file which invokes a aws instance and host a static website but post running this terratest module, it gives an undefined error for destroy function.

Terratest code:

```
`package test

import (
    "fmt"
    http_helper "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/http-helper"
    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform"

    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestTerraformHelloWorldExample(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()

    // Construct the terraform options with default retryable errors to handle the most common
    // retryable errors in terraform testing.
    terraformOptions := terraform.WithDefaultRetryableErrors(t, &terraform.Options{
        // Set the path to the Terraform code that will be tested.
        TerraformDir: "../project-3/webserver",
    })
    terraform.InitAndApply(t, terraformOptions)

    defer terraform.Destory(t, terraformOptions)
    publicIp := terraform.Output(t, terraformOptions, "public_ip")
    url := fmt.Sprintf("http://%s:8080", publicIp)
    http_helper.HttpGetWithRetry(t, url, nil, 200, "I have made  a Terraform module", 30, 5*time.Second)
}
`
~~~~~~~~~~~~


Output when I ran the test :
> go test webserver_test.go
# command-line-arguments [command-line-arguments.test]
./webserver_test.go:23:18: undefined: terraform.Destory
FAIL    command-line-arguments [build failed]
FAIL 

Tried to figure out why this is an issue but not able to get root cause. Could someone please help.


I did check the documentation and couple of tutorial video but didn't get much insight on the issue.
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems a typo, so try:

```
defer terraform. Destroy(t, terraformOptions)
```

instead of

```
defer terraform.Destory(t, terraformOptions)
```

See https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/e1570b571f726e7d2389b059519101a345b442d6/modules/terraform/destroy.go#L9

Comment: Thank you ..!
it worked post adding - defer terraform.Destroy(t, terraformOptions)